# ec2 spot instance graceful termination

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation

We are using ec2 spot instances in one of the use-case, and we need to do graceful decommission of the instance (spot instance) if its marked for termination using 2 min termination notice.

From the online reading I found its little difficult to test the code for this graceful decommission because of unproductive behaviour of of spot market.

To test this i just keep running following python script on spot instance

```
while requests.get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/spot/termination-time").status_code != "200":  
    sleep(5)

smtplib.SMTP('localhost').sendmail("me@abc.com", "me@abc.com", "Instance Terminated : $INSTANCE_ID")
```

But this never worked for me.

anyone can help me with this ?

Comment: should work. does sending the email work for you?

Comment: yes if I just run the last line the I do get email, but it doesn't work in termination notice scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

status_code is an **integer** based on doc here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response

so basically, even when you get a 200 response you will compare 200 with "200" and will keep sleeping. modify the code to:

```
while requests.get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/spot/termination-time").status_code != 200:  
    sleep(5)
```

Comment: You could test it by pointing to a different URL that returns a `200` response (eg a file on Amazon S3), just to see if the logic works correctly.